# Hover effect over image with text css

Tags: html, css

How to use an overlay effect over an image with text inside.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjs96/ukmdj5d4/6/)

```
<div class="ft-item">
  <span class="ft-image">
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/irjHmR/backwater.jpg" alt="featured Scroller" draggable="false">
        </span>
  <div class="ft-data">
    <a class="text-upper" href="#">
      <h5 class="itemh5">Test Content</h5>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried by using this but it doesnot works as my need. [example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_slidetop)

Comment: In this do you want only the `ft-data` to have the effect?

Comment: no full ft-item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. I have changed some css.

```css
.ft-item {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.itemh5 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.ft-image {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.ft-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.ft-data {
  background: rgba(30, 110, 30, 0.68);
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

.ft-item:hover .ft-data {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.ft-data .text-upper {
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.ft-foot {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  background: #000;
}

.ft-hotel,
.ft-plane,
.ft-tea,
.ft-boat,
.ft-car {
  float: left;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  color: #292c2f;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.text-upper {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.ft-title {
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.ft-offer {
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.panpad {
  padding: 0px;
}

.ft-foot {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  background: #484848;
}

.ft-foot ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.ft-foot li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 2px;
}

.inclusion {
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 0 10px 0;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.inclusion span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.inclusion i {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body panpad">
            <div class="ft-item">
                <span class="ft-image">
                  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/irjHmR/backwater.jpg" alt="featured Scroller" draggable="false">
                </span>

                <div class="ft-data">
                    <a class="text-upper" href="#"><h5 class="itemh5">Test Content</h5></a>
                </div>
                <div class="ft-foot">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="inclusion"><i class="fa fa-male" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Guide</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class="inclusion"><i class="fa fa-car" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Site seeing</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class="inclusion"><i class="fa fa-building-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Hotels</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class="inclusion"><i class="fa fa-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Transportation</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class="inclusion"><i class="fa fa-cutlery" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Food</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="ft-foot-ex">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```